# Which datatype to use for this RedisCache implementation?

Tags: c#, redis, stackexchange.redis

I have the below DB table structure:

```
Id(string)  Type(string)  BeginDate(datetime) CloseDate(dateime) Source(string)
"+ww100"     "L"           23-JAN-20               23-APRIL-20     XYZ
"+ww100"     "L"           23-JAN-20               23-APRIL-20     XYZ
 ---         ---              ---                      ---         ---
```

As you might have observed, this table does not have any primary key, which means there could be duplicate data. Now I need to store this table data in Redis cache and retrieve it subsequently.
Example: I might wanna search based on the Id, even if there are multiple records, I want to retrieve them all and do the processing.
Since I am a newbie to Redis, could you please suggest me which datatype to use for this use-case? Since the Key's are not unique, storing as a dictionary type of data structure will not be possible I think!
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are not interested in retrieving or modifying a field in a record, but most of the time retrieve the whole record, you can serialize it in your preferred format, like JSON or simply as:

```
+ww100|L|23-JAN-20|23-APRIL-20|XYZ
```

Separating by `|` or your preferred separator, make sure your separator won't be part of a data field or escape accordingly.

**Using a sorted set**

As there is nothing to differentiate from two records that are the same, you can simply keep a counter.

Say you are storing:

```
Id(string)  Type(string)  BeginDate(datetime) CloseDate(dateime) Source(string)
"+ww100"     "L"           23-JAN-20               23-APRIL-20     XYZ
"+ww100"     "L"           23-JAN-20               23-APRIL-20     XYZ
"+ww101"     "E"           24-JAN-20               24-APRIL-20     ABC
```

You insert with [`ZADD`](https://redis.io/commands/zadd), using `INCR` option. If it is new, it will insert. If it is a duplicate, it will increase the count.

```
> ZADD myData INCR 1 +ww100|L|23-JAN-20|23-APRIL-20|XYZ
"1"
> ZADD myData INCR 1 +ww100|L|23-JAN-20|23-APRIL-20|XYZ
"2"
> ZADD myData INCR 1 +ww101|E|24-JAN-20|24-APRIL-20|ABC
"1"
> ZRANGEBYSCORE myData -inf +inf WITHSCORES
1) "+ww101|E|24-JAN-20|24-APRIL-20|ABC"
2) "1"
3) "+ww100|L|23-JAN-20|23-APRIL-20|XYZ"
4) "2"
```

Note how the duplicated record appears once but with the count.

You can then query for a given ID using [`ZSCAN`](https://redis.io/commands/zscan) to get all the records matching an ID:

```
> ZSCAN myData 0 MATCH "+ww100|*"
1) "0"
2) 1) "+ww100|L|23-JAN-20|23-APRIL-20|XYZ"
   2) "2"
```

The downside of `ZSCAN` is that you may need to call multiple times until you get the cursor back in zero, and you are iterating through all the records server-side.

**Using a sorted list per ID**

If you want to have best performance to query per ID, then use one sorted set per ID.

Keep a set with all IDs.

To store, then you use [`SADD`](https://redis.io/commands/sadd) first to add/ensure the ID:

```
> SADD myDataIDs +ww100
(integer) 1
> ZADD myData:+ww100 INCR 1 +ww100|L|23-JAN-20|23-APRIL-20|XYZ
"1"
```

The downside here is that to get all records, you need to call `SMEMBERS myDataIDs` to get all IDs, and then call `ZRANGEBYSCORE` for each ID.

Make sure to use [pipelining](https://stackexchange.github.io/StackExchange.Redis/PipelinesMultiplexers.html) to save Round Trip Times when appropriate.

And you can use [Lua scripts](https://redis.io/commands/eval) to optimize some operations. Here for example to get all records:

```
local keys = redis.call('SMEMBERS', KEYS[1])
local r = {}
for i, key in ipairs(keys) do
  r[i] = redis.call('ZRANGEBYSCORE', 'myData:'..key, '-inf', '+inf', 'WITHSCORES')
end
return r
```