# Storing data of the last couple of minutes in a redis list

Tags: list, go, redis, queue

I'm working on the caching the database of a system and I have faced this problem:

We have some remote devices that send a log to the server each second! Since we have many of this devices we can't just store all the data in an ordinary database table. We actually need to have fast access to the last 5 minutes of logs each device has sent.Logs are in json but we map them to Go structs. Each log has some data like:

```
    type Log struct {
    DeviceID        string
    CompanyID       uint
    DeviceTime      time.Time
    Latitude        float64
    Longitude       float64
    Altitude        float64
    SpeedOTG        float32
}
```

We are using **redis** to store the data on the ram.

**My Problem**:

The task is to store all logs of the last 5 minutes of each device in a list. Also I should retrieve these data when provided a **cach key**. I have to make some thing like a queue. When its full (it contains the log of last 5 minutes) every new entry goes in and old entries  should go out. How ever if the list still doesn't contain the last 5 minutes then nothing goes out! all calculations are done based the **DeviceTime** filed defined above.

At first I thought about a list with determined size(5*60) logs to store but there is no grantee that there is a new log every second!

Comment: Why redis? You can store and process the logs in your go program, then save it somewhere else in batches.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Store your logs in [Redis Streams](https://redis.io/topics/streams-intro). To insert, you use the [`XADD` command](https://redis.io/commands/xadd).[[Go Redis Example](https://github.com/go-redis/redis/blob/master/commands_test.go#L3402)].

You can store all devices in one stream, or use one stream per device.

Here, assuming one stream per device and keeping a set of device IDs, you would insert:

```
SADD devices myDeviceID
XADD logs:myDeviceID * DeviceID myDeviceID CompanyID myCompanyID DeviceTime "myDeviceTime"
     ... SpeedOTG "mySpeedOTG"
```

The set `devices` is to keep a list of device IDs in case you want to retrieve the data for all devices and you don't want to rely on keeping it in go (client-side) or using SCAN. To retrieve all devices logs, you'd use a pattern similar to the one I described in [Which datatype to use for this RedisCache implementation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59148859/which-datatype-to-use-for-this-rediscache-implementation/59906632#59906632), Lua script example at the end.

One of the benefits of streams if field-compression: as you keep your fields consistent (same fields in same order), Redis optimizes by not repeating the field names on every entry.

By using the `*`, you are letting Redis set a timestamp as entry ID. You can use your own timestamp as ID for as long as you are sure it will be strictly increasing. You cannot add to a stream with an ID lower than the last ID added.

You could use [`XTRIM`](https://redis.io/commands/xtrim) to keep your list down to 300 entries, but as you said, you cannot rely on consistent per-second XADDs.

To keep it precisely down to the last 5 minutes, you can use:

```
XRANGE logs:myDeviceID - + COUNT 1
```

This retrieves the first (oldest) entry. You compare it with the timestamp of the newly-added latest entry, and if older than 5 minutes, you delete it with [`XDEL`](https://redis.io/commands/xdel).

You repeat until the oldest entry is not older than 5 minutes.

Of course, doing this logic client side implies a lot of round trips, affecting your performance. So I suggest you use a [Lua Script](https://redis.io/commands/eval) to do it Redis-server-side. You can use EVAL to pass the script every time. But it is better if you [load the script](https://redis.io/commands/script-load) once and then use [EVALSHA](https://redis.io/commands/evalsha).

The script:

```
redis.call('SADD', KEYS[1], ARGV[2])

local latestID = redis.call('XADD', 'logs:'..ARGV[2], '*', 'DeviceID', ARGV[2],
                            'OtherFields', ARGV[3])
local latestTime = tonumber(string.sub(latestID, 1, string.find(latestID, '-') - 1))

local oldestID = redis.call('XRANGE', 'logs:'..ARGV[2], '-', '+', 'COUNT', '1')
oldestID = oldestID[1][1]
local oldestTime = tonumber(string.sub(oldestID, 1, string.find(oldestID, '-') - 1))

local maxTime = tonumber(ARGV[1])

while (latestTime - oldestTime) > maxTime do
    redis.call('XDEL', 'logs:'..ARGV[2], oldestID)
    oldestID = redis.call('XRANGE', 'logs:'..ARGV[2], '-', '+', 'COUNT', '1')
    oldestID = oldestID[1][1]
    oldestTime = tonumber(string.sub(oldestID, 1, string.find(oldestID, '-') - 1))
end
return { 'Added: '..latestID, 'Device: '..ARGV[2], 'Stream Key: logs:'..ARGV[2],
         'Length: '..redis.call('XLEN', 'logs:'..ARGV[2]) }
```

The parameters:

```
EVALSHA <shaId> 1 devices 300000 myDeviceID ...
                                            ^ARGV[3...]: the rest of fields
                                 ^ARGV[2]: DeviceID
                          ^ARGV[1]: logging time desired (ms), 5 minutes = 300000
                  ^KEYS[1]: the set key and prefix to device log keys
                ^numkeys
```

Using streams you get a lot of features, like range by timestamp, or consumer groups.

But the bottom line is that to keep your logs capped by time, use a Lua script. You could do it with lists as well, storing the log entries encoded in one string: `timestamp:valuesSerialized` and use a similar approach with Lua to add-check-trim in one atomic operation.